# How to properly format array of Windows Server Services for install-windowsfeature

Tags: powershell, windows-server

How do I format an array of Windows Services names to be used with the install-windowsfeature cmdlet?

I have a script that prompts user for the source and destination servers, as well as ask for their credentials. It then pulls the list of installed services and takes only the names. The output I'm getting wants to add `@{Name=` before the beginning of each service name (with an ending bracket afterwards), so my efforts have been focused trying to convert the object into a string to remove the extra characters, and separate them with a comma to give to install-windowsfeature.

This is where I run into issues. I've tried many different iterations of this script, including trying to use the .tostring and out-string commands, both on the entire array, and using a foreach loop to run it on the individual objects.

Yesterday I was also trying to use the .trim commands to remove leading/trailing characters, but it kept saying that the module wasn't installed, and I couldn't find out what the name of the module I needed to install was, so I gave up trying that way.

```
$srcServ = read-host "Which server are you pulling the services from?"

$dstServ = read-host "What is the server you are installing on?" 

#get credentials to authenticate to servers
$usrCred = get-credential

#pull list of installed services from srcServ
$serviceList = get-windowsfeature -computername $srcServ -credential $usrCred | where installed | select name

write-host "`n"

#convert array objects to strings
foreach ($service in $serviceList){

        $service = $service.Name.ToString()

        $finally += $service + ","
    }

write-host "`n"

write-host $finally -separator "`n"

#write-host -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor yellow "The following list of " $finally.count " services was pulled from " $srcServ " to be installed on " $dstServ ". Is this correct?"

#install-windowsfeature -confirm -name $dstServ -credential $usrCred $finally
```

I've been working on this for about two days now, trying many different ways to get this to work, but still no luck. I've only been making changes in the section after the $serviceList variable, but I also was trying to use .tostring and out-string at the end of that line. Also, I was formerly trying to append in the foreach loop directly back into $serviceList, but right now I have another variable instead ($finally).

I've been using the `write-host $finally` to see what the output is, and currently it seems to be outputting the list 3 times, into a single-item in the array. The first time is just the name with no delineation, second time the names are in a `@{Name=[serviceNameHere]}` format, then the last time is in the desired format with comma delineation but there is no separation between the three copies.

the bottom two lines that are commented out is what I'm using to initiate the install on the servers. When I was running the entire script (including those sections) the errors I was getting was either complaining that I was giving it objects instead of strings, or that the service didn't exist (because it started with the @{name... thing or it read the whole array/string as one giant string).

I've tried sending the array directly to Install-WindowsFeature, I've tried trying to change the objects in the array to strings to remove the @{} stuff using both `.tostring` and `out-string`, I've tried removing characters from the objects/strings with `.trim` and `.trimstart`.

Comment: ```select name``` filters the input from the pipeline and returns new objects that have *just* the named property (or properties), but they're still *objects* with properties. If you want to return a list of strings you can use ```select-object -ExpandProperty Name``` which returns output that contains the *value* from the named property for each object instead - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.4#-expandproperty